# Current Disk Space requirements for a pruned parity node?

Tags: parity

I want to keep the disk usage to under 30GB, is it possible with `--pruned fast` ? Or any other config.

If its not possible, what is the smallest disk requirements as of recently

Comment: 25 GB ---------

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps:

```
| ID | Pruning / DB Config | Verification    | Available History          | ETH        | ETC        | EXP        | MSC        | Parity CLI Options                         |
|====|=====================|=================|============================|============|============|============|============|============================================|
| 00 | archive +Fat +Trace | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + States        | 385     GB |  90.0   GB |   5.6   GB |  25.0   GB | --pruning archive --tracing on --fat-db on |
| 01 | archive +Trace      | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + States        | 334     GB |  90.0   GB |   5.8   GB |  21.0   GB | --pruning archive --tracing on             |
| 02 | archive             | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + States        | 326     GB |  91.0   GB |   5.5   GB |  30.0   GB | --pruning archive                          |
| 03 | fast +Fat +Trace    | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + Recent States |  37.0   GB |  13.0   GB |   1.3   GB |   3.5   GB | --tracing on --fat-db on                   |
| 04 | fast +Trace         | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + Recent States |  34.0   GB |  13.0   GB |   1.2   GB |   3.5   GB | --tracing on                               |
| 05 | fast                | Full/No-Warp    | All Blocks + Recent States |  26.0   GB |   9.7   GB |   1.1   GB |   3.0   GB | --no-warp                                  |
| 06 | fast +Warp          | PoW-Only/Warp   | All Blocks + Recent States |  25.0   GB |   9.6   GB |   0.96  GB |   2.6   GB |                                            |
| 07 | fast +Warp -Ancient | No-Ancient/Warp | Recent Blocks + States     |   5.3   GB |   2.9   GB |   0.13  GB |   0.19  GB | --no-ancient-blocks                        |
| 08 | light               | Headers/Light   | No Blocks + No State       |       5 MB |       3 MB |       5 MB |       4 MB | --light                                    |
```

(Data from around September 2017.)

Comment: Thanks, Afri. How do i set `no-ancient-blocks` via conf file?

Comment: I'm going to leave this here in case anyone wants to store this table locally: https://i.imgur.com/o1Q58lO.png

Comment: Hi Afri could you please update this for August 2018 now? even rough figures will help.