# Minimal space to synchronize Parity

Tags: parity, nodes

I've an instance with a 40GB hard drive and I'm having difficulties to synchronize with parity.

I've used `--pruning auto --pruning-history 3` but around block 4200000 I run out of space, the folder with the chain data has a size around 35GB.

Does anyone know if it is possible to synchronize parity with this space limitation?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28541/current-disk-space-requirements-for-a-pruned-parity-node/31195#31195